# Run PowerShell on Windows Container start and keep it running

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile, windows-container

I've been experimenting and searching for a long time without finding an answer that works.
I have a Windows Container and I need to embed a startup script for each time a new container is created.
All the answers I found suggest one of the following:

1. Add the command to the dockerfile - this is not good because it will only run when the image is built. I need it to run every single time a new container is created from the image,
2. use docker exec after starting a container - this is also not what I need. These images are intended to be "shippable". I need the script to run without any special action apart from creating a new container.
3. Using ENTRYPOINT - I had 2 cases here. It either fails and immediately exits. Or it succeeds but the container stops. I need it to keep running.

Basically, the goal of this is to do some initial configuration on the container when it starts and keep it running.
The actions are around generating a GUID and registering the hostname. These have to be unique which is why I need to run them immediately when the container starts.

Comment: Any command/script passed to ENTRYPOINT should run continuously for the container to remain alive. When that command terminates successfully, the container will exit. A hack around this limitation of ENTRYPOINT is to make your powershell script run on a infinte loop after executing the intended code.

Comment: For a Linux container, the `CMD` gets passed to the `ENTRYPOINT` as arguments, and typically an `ENTRYPOINT` script will end with a Bourne shell command `exec "$@"` to take the arguments, run them as a command, and replace the script with it.  I don't know PowerShell at all, but is there an equivalent invocation to run the command-line arguments as a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like CMD in the dockerfile is all I needed. I used:
CMD powershell -file 
I simply checked in the script if it's the first time it is running